# Add second input when filled in more then 2 chars. (javascript) (hard one)

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an form with an input field, with javascript it will make an same input field beneath the first one when users put in more then 2 chars. The code for this is:

```
 <h7> Optie 1: </h7><input type="text" name="input1" onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 1 && treated[this.name] != 1){ addOne(); treated[this.name] = '1'; }"  id="productoptiesadd"> <h7>&euro;</h7> <input type="text" name="price1" id="productoptiesaddprice">
```

&

```
        <script>
        treated = new Object(); 
        inputNumber = 1;

        function addOne() {

            //Create an input type dynamically.
            var divElement = document.createElement("div");

            var element = document.createElement("input");
            inputNumber++;
            element.setAttribute("name", "input" +inputNumber);
            element.setAttribute("onkeyup", "if (this.value.length > 1 && treated[this.name] != 1){ addOne(); treated[this.name] = '1'; }");
            element.setAttribute("id", "productoptiesadd");

            var price = document.createElement("input");
            price.setAttribute("name", "price" +inputNumber);
            price.setAttribute("id", "productoptiesaddprice");

            var foo = document.getElementById("japroductopties");

            var htag = document.createElement("h7");
            htag.innerHTML = "Optie " + inputNumber + ":";

            var htags = document.createElement("h7");
            htags.innerHTML = " € ";

            divElement.appendChild(htag);
            divElement.appendChild(element);
            divElement.appendChild(htags);
            divElement.appendChild(price);
            foo.appendChild(divElement);
            }
    </script>
```

This is working fine, but now I get my next challenge, because the first input fields is to add an product option, and I got an other option below it which should give the discount.

Here comes my main problem: "How can i get as many discount input field as there are product option fields."

To give you more information here is an screenshot of how i had in mind of the layout:

[image: Example layout]

here is the HTML code of that part but the last input fields should be the same amount as there are option input fields.

```
<div id="productoptiecheat"></div>
                            <div id="japroductopties">
                               <h7> Optie 1: </h7><input type="text" name="input1" onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 1 && treated[this.name] != 1){ addOne(); treated[this.name] = '1'; }"  id="productoptiesadd"> <h7>&euro;</h7> <input type="text" name="price1" id="productoptiesaddprice">
                            </div><!-- Japroductopties -->
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Product in aanbieding</label>
                        <select class="select" title="product in aanbieding" name="productinaanbieding" id="productaanbieding" onchange='SwitchHiddenDiv2();'>
                            <option value="jaaanbieding">Ja</option>
                            <option value="neeaanbieding">Nee</option>
                        </select>
                            <div id="productoptiecheat"></div>
                            <div id="jaaanbieding">
                                <select class="select" title="plaats vd aanbieding" name="aanbiedingplaats" id="aanbiedingplaats">
                                    <option value="hompagerubriek">Aanbieding tonen op homepage & rubriek</option>
                                    <option value="rubriek">Aanbieding tonen in rubriek</option>
                                    <option value="homepage">Aanbieding tonen op de homepage</option>
                                    <option value="niet">Aanbieding niet tonen</option>
                                </select><br />
                                <h7>Optie 1: Normaal bedrag: <b>&euro;</b></h7><input type="text" id="productoptiesadd" /> <h7>Aanbieding:</h7> <input type="text" id="productoptiesaddprice" /><br />
                                <h7>Optie 2: Normaal bedrag: <b>&euro;</b></h7><input type="text" id="productoptiesadd" /> <h7>Aanbieding:</h7> <input type="text" id="productoptiesaddprice" /><br />
                                <h7>Optie 3: Normaal bedrag: <b>&euro;</b></h7><input type="text" id="productoptiesadd" /> <h7>Aanbieding:</h7> <input type="text" id="productoptiesaddprice" /><br />
                                <h7>Optie 4: Normaal bedrag: <b>&euro;</b></h7><input type="text" id="productoptiesadd" /> <h7>Aanbieding:</h7> <input type="text" id="productoptiesaddprice" /><br />
                            </div><!-- jaaanbieding -->
                            <div class="clear"></div>
```

I hope some1 can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you want to add one of these lines:

```
<h7>Optie 1: Normaal bedrag: <b>&euro;</b></h7><input type="text" id="productoptiesadd" /> <h7>Aanbieding:</h7> <input type="text" id="productoptiesaddprice" /><br />
```

... for every time your function above adds a product/price option.

I would say to add a DIV to your HTML below the name="aanbiedingplaats" SELECT tag. Call it id="discounts" and add this code to your function:

document.getElementById("discounts").innerHTML+=yourOptionHTML;

I'm using innerHTML here but feel free to expand that into function similar to your addOne().